# Getting cursor position and relevant data from Highmaps

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm currently trying to integrate `Highcharts` (or more specifically Highmaps) into my React app.

What I want to achieve is to be able to click/hover on a country in the map, and the relevant information (e.g. country name or any relevant data) can be extracted to be displayed somewhere else in the app (e.g. to update the selectedCountry state in a parent component).

At the moment it seems to me the only way to display the information is through `tooltip` which doesn't really let me interact with data outside the chart. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easily possible to use click and mouseOver callback functions for getting information about clicked/hovered point. You can find information about these two functions in official Highcharts API:
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.point.events.click

```
plotOptions: {
  map: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: this.hoverFunction.bind(this)
      }
    }
  }
}


hoverFunction = (e) => { 
  alert(e.target.code)
}
```

Live example with official Highcharts-React wrapper:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wkb1n2?file=index.js